# How to add CSS to sanitized text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working with a web project where I have full control on the "client web page" (I can add or modify HTML / CSS / JS)

The content management system is, however, not under our control. That CMS exposes one text box where I can input some description text that will be displayed on client web page but does html sanitization which remove all html tags. This prevent me from styling my text field.

Basically

```
<h2 class="red-text">Some Text I Wanna Style</h2>
```

Become just `Some Text I Wanna Style`
I trust that there is some way around this as I have full access to the client side which means I can implement my own "markup system" like BBCode?

```
[b]bolded text[/b]
```

Where I can find the tag and use JS to transform it to appropriate CSS class.

My question is that: Am I approaching this issue the correct way? Is there any standard/common method/library to solve this kind of problem?

Edit: I do not have access to the server side, only the client side

Comment: I would recommend to use a BBCode parser / HTML generator like https://www.npmjs.com/package/bbcode-parser on the server-side.

Comment: Thanks @wiomoc. Can that library be applied on client side? And I see that package is quite old... I'll check that out anyways

Comment: bbcode are parsed server-side, you can try to do this with a js parser....with regex

Comment: I know that this is probably an annoying comment but: `Am I approaching this issue the correct way?` No, the correct way would be to solve that on the server-side. Using JavaScript for that would result in annoying flickering of the content, might bring problems with SEO, and various other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only using light markup, then try using Markdown! Its ridiculously popular and has a million libraries in every language conceivable (most of all JS).

Almost certainly the easiest thing to use, given the simplicity of the libraries that exist for it. If its suitable for this project, I highly recommend it :)

I imagine that some libraries support extending the syntax with your own, custom rules too!